Unable to share record access through Apex Sharing Rules
In my example, an Apex sharing rule is used to share access to project records from object Project__c to a public group Project Management Team when Priority__c in Project is 'High'.
For the same I have created Apex sharing reason in the Project as Project_Sharing_Rule.
Trigger class:
trigger ProjectSharingTrigger on Project__c (after insert, after update) {
    if (Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUpdate) {
        ProjectSharingHelper.shareHighPriorityProjects(Trigger.new);
    }
}

Apex Class code:
public class ProjectSharingHelper {
    
    public static void shareHighPriorityProjects(List<Project__c> projects) {
        List<Project__Share> sharesToInsert = new List<Project__Share>();

        Id groupId = [SELECT Id FROM Group WHERE Name = 'Project_management_team' LIMIT 1].Id;

  Projects = [ SELECT id, priority__c FROM Project__c];

        for (Project__c proj : projects) {
            if (proj.Priority__c == 'High') {
                Project__Share projectShare = new Project__Share();
                projectShare.ParentId = proj.Id; 
                projectShare.UserOrGroupId = groupId; 
                projectShare.AccessLevel = 'Read'; 
                projectShare.RowCause = Schema.Project__Share.RowCause.Project_Sharing_Rule__c; 

                sharesToInsert.add(projectShare);
            }
        }

        if (!sharesToInsert.isEmpty()) {
            try {
                insert sharesToInsert;
                System.debug('High-priority project shared with team successfully.');
            } catch (DMLException e){
                System.debug('Error sharing projects: ' + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}

Error while creating Project with high priority :

ProjectSharingTrigger: execution of AfterInsert caused by: System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject
Class.ProjectSharingHelper.shareHighPriorityProjects: line 6, column 1
Trigger.ProjectSharingTrigger: line 3, column 1


Check if the groupId contains any value or not. Is there any reason you are querying the projects because you are not using it anywhere in the code and looks unnecessary.

The Name field in Group object corresponds to the Label.  Do you have underscores in your group Label?

The query to fetch the group ID is failing because it does not find any group with the name 'Project_management_team'.
To fix this, you should modify your code to handle the scenario where the query returns no rows. You can use the safe navigation operator (?.) to avoid the error.
public class ProjectSharingHelper {

  public static void shareHighPriorityProjects(List<Project__c> projects) {
    List<Project__Share> sharesToInsert = new List<Project__Share>();
    Id groupId = [SELECT Id FROM Group WHERE Name = 'Project_management_team' LIMIT 1]?.Id;

    if (groupId != null) {
      for (Project__c proj : projects) {
        if (proj.Priority__c == 'High') {
          Project__Share projectShare = new Project__Share();
          projectShare.ParentId = proj.Id; 
          projectShare.UserOrGroupId = groupId; 
          projectShare.AccessLevel = 'Read'; 
          projectShare.RowCause = Schema.Project__Share.RowCause.Project_Sharing_Rule__c; 

          sharesToInsert.add(projectShare);
        }
      }
    } else {
      System.debug('Group not found!');
    }

    if (!sharesToInsert.isEmpty()) {
      try {
        insert sharesToInsert;
        System.debug('High-priority project shared with team successfully.');
      } catch (DMLException e) {
        System.debug('Error sharing projects: ' + e.getMessage());
      }
    }
  }
}

For more information regarding to the error refer to this: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000385697&type=1

N.B. the test for empty collection is unnecessary as DML on empty lists does not burndown limits
